# Passing a type fun<'a> in parameter?

Tags: types, parameters, f#

How can I pass a type `fun<'a>` in parameter in F#?

```
Example -> type myClass(a : int, myDelegate : fun<'a>)
    let theFunc = myDelegate
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you want

```
type mytype<'a> (a:int,myDelegate:'a->unit) = 
    let theFunc = myDelegate
```

Alternatively, if `fun` is some type defined elsewhere you will need to use backtick notation as `fun` is a reserved word in F#

```
type mytype<'a> (a:int,myDelegate:``fun``<'a>) = 
    let theFunc = myDelegate
```